# Viewmodel wants IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this error when I am trying to return the viewmodel.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Tp1WebStore3.Models.Panier]'.

Any idea of what is the problem ?

PanierController.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Controllers
 {
     public class PanierController : Controller
     {
         Tp1WebStoreDBEntities db = new Tp1WebStoreDBEntities();

         //
         // GET: /ShoppingCart/
         public ActionResult Index()
         {
             var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

             // Set up our ViewModel
             var viewModel = new ShoppingCartViewModel
             {
                 CartItems = cart.GetCartItems(),
                 CartTotal = cart.GetTotal()
             };
             // Return the view
             return View(viewModel);    <== the error occurs here
         }
```

ShoppingCartViewModels.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using Tp1WebStore3.Models;

 namespace Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels
 {
     public class ShoppingCartViewModel
     {
         public List<Panier> CartItems { get; set; }
         public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Comment: which part of the error you don't understand ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the model correctly in you view.

Try this. Put it on top of your view.

```
@model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel
```

You will find your `Index.cshtml` view file in the `Views` folder.

Comment: When I put this line at the top of ShoppingCartViewModel.cs it gave me an error a namspace cannot directly contains member such as field or method

Comment: @user3127986: That is not your view, you will find your Index.cshtml file in the Views folder.

Comment: @user3127986: any luck? Did this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Give the error a good read. It tells you exactly what is wrong in pretty plain English. You're view wants an IEnumerable of type Painer but you're passing in a ShoppingCartViewModel.

Switch

```
@model IEnumerable<Painer>
```

with

```
@model ShoppingCartViewModel
```

in your view. Namespaces wont match what I wrote above but this should be on line 1 of your view.